# How can we restrict a wall post to be viewable only by logged in user in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I've a task of posting to facebook wall, which works without any problem, but the botleneck comes when i have to limit the visibility of this wall post to only the user whome i sent it for, i mean only to logged in user and not to anyone else. My following code for posting to facebook users wall works fine, but how can i limit it as mentioned.
Here's my code;

```
$sendTo = $friendIdArr[1]; //id of facebook user (friend)
                $uniqueCode = sha1( uniqid() );
                $link = BASE_URL . "invite/accept_invitation/".$uniqueCode;
                //$link = "http://www.yahoo.com";
                $message = "Please click on the link to accept invitation";
                $attachment = array("message" => $message, "link" => $link);
                $sendMessage = $objFacebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/", "post", $attachment);
```

This wall post is being displayed correctly on users wall, but how can i make it such that no other user except for him can view it. 
My main purpose of doing this is : when a user click on the invitation link sent to his post, i need to verify from my side that if its the same user to which i've posted the message for. Are there any other ways thru which i can achieve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by **Privacy** parameter on Graph API. You should have access_token which you can gather from Facebook PHP API with the function getAccessToken().

Search for the privacy keyword, you can see the parameters for setting up who to show: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I was just about to add an answer explaining this. One caveat though is that you can't override privacy when posting to the wall of a user other than the current session user. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that anyway, but just keep it in mind